# Building a Rails app with Aptana Studio 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana

I'm new to Rails and Aptana.  I'm trying to create a new Rails Project (call it "MyProj").  I get the following error:
 sh: /c/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/rails: C:/Projects/railsinstaller/sgae/Ruby1.9.2/bin/ruby.exe: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and what I need to do to fix this?   Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, it's looking in the wrong location. My RailsInstaller didn't put ruby.exe in  C:/Projects/railsinstaller/sgae/Ruby1.9.2/bin/. It put it in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin, so the question becomes, how the hell do we tell Aptana Studio this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are running Windows, I don't know/use it so probably I will not help you too much but it seems Aptana try to run rails but can't find a suitable ruby interpreter at the location it aspects.

Are you able to run irb from the terminal?

Maybe you can find some useful hint about Rails installation in windows here http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial?version=3.2#sec:rails_installer_windows

Hope this can help ;)

Comment: I'll look through the installer doc on the link you sent.  Thanks for the help.